# White balance of an image with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to change this image color by using white balance with `OpenCV-4.2.0` on `python3.7`.

[image: First image]

I would like to know if exists any way to modify the image temperature and the image tint and get some result like that.

[image: Second image]

I've searched but I didn't find anything to change directly these values.

thank you.

EDITED:

I got a new image and it is a real condition of my image:

[image: Third image]

Comment: The **blue** color channel is missing from the input image (all blue elements are zeros). There is no way to restore the blue channel correctly. In case the output is for aesthetic purpose, there are things you can do, but you can't reconstruct the true colors.

Comment: Almost Cris Luengo! This solved a good part of my problems, but I'm using a real time capture and I can't lose more process during the capture. With the faster code of this solution I still losing 4/5 fps. I was thinking in some features where I can change directly these values.

Comment: Oh, it's very good to know about it, thank you Rotem! Actually, I modified the first image blue channel to get a similar result. Now I edited and put a real situation image.